# Pseudo elements on tables?

Tags: css, html-table, pseudo-element

I'm trying to apply a pseudo element to a `<tr>` but turns out it's not working as expected. I'm not sure if i'm missing anything or if it's just simply not possible.

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jDwCq/

Notice that if you change the display of `tr` to `display: block;`, the pseudo element will show up, but it is displayed as a block rather than a table, which i need.

Is it possible or am I doomed?

Comment: exactly what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Just trying to make a cool hover effect for the table rows. When you hover the rows, i want to make the height expand. Or i want it to look like it at least (i don't want to add padding or change height because then the siblings will be affected). I was going to use `:before` and `:after` to make it look like the top and bottom of the row becomes bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    tr:hover td{
      background: pink or whatever;
    }
tr:hover td:after{
  background: yellow;
}
```

I don't see the need for pseudo elements.

I will say that having an element, which isn't a cell, directly inside a row, is asking for pain.
You could always have a pseudo-element inside every cell of a targeted row, though. With the right css, there will be no perceptible difference.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jDwCq/7/

Comment: I'm not sure you understand why i need pseudo elements.

Comment: Based on my experience of tables and css, anything you want to do with a row can be done by styling cells, and it's usually more consistent. I've added a change to your jsfiddle to my answer, to show what I mean.

Comment: Success! I mean, i figured out it really looks like crap, and i'm probably not going to use it, but it works! Here's a fiddle with the idea i had: http://jsfiddle.net/LvGQD/ I wish i could throw in some css3 transitions for those pseudo elements, to make them slide into place, or maybe fade.

Answer (score 1):

```
table tr:before{
position: relative; /* Needed for pseudo elem */
display: block; /*Uncomment me and see what happens*/
}
```

this should work...

Comment: The only difference is you're using before instead of after.. it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `display: inline-block;` to TDs, and give them a width (~33% each)... and remove `position: absolute` from the pseudoelement.

That's it: http://jsfiddle.net/jDwCq/6/

```
   table tr {
        /*position: relative; /* (REALLY NOT) Needed for pseudo elem */
        display: block; /*Uncomment me and see what happens*/
    }

    td {
        width: 32.9%; /* ADD THIS */
        display: inline-block; /* AND THIS */
    }

    table tr:after {
        /*position: absolute; REMOVE THIS TOO */
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        text-indent: -99999px;
        background: red;
        height: 2px;
        /*width: 100%; NOT NEEDED */
    }
```

Comment: The benifit of using `display: table;` is that it automatically sets the width of the column depending on the content. Sure, i could hardcode the widths, but i would very much prefer to have it display as a table. That's not possible, right?

Comment: Of course, but where, in your original fiddle, did u use `display: table` ? :)

Comment: Ah, i meant to say `display: table-row;`, and i believe that is the default for table rows (that would make sense).

Comment: Ah ok, it is (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html), but your `tr:after` won't work... i can only make it work like above, hope that helps...

Comment: Yup, i figured. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To make the rows appear bigger using `::before` and/or `::after` pseudo-elements you'd have to apply those elements to the `td` elements, but select the `td` elements based on the `:hover` of the `tr`:

```
td::before,
td::after {
    /* defines the default states/sizes */
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}

tr:hover td::before,
tr:hover td::after {
    /* adjusts attributes based on the parent tr's :hover event */
    height: 1em;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jDwCq/9/).

However, if the aim is to 'look cool<sup>1</sup>' then I'd suggest adjusting the styling of the `td` elements themselves (since that way they can be animated), rather than using the pseudo-elements which just 'appear':

```
td {
    padding: 0;
    -moz-transition: padding 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: padding 1s linear;
    -o-transition: padding 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: padding 1s linear;
    transition: padding 1s linear;
}

tr:hover td {
    padding: 1em 0;
    -moz-transition: padding 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: padding 1s linear;
    -o-transition: padding 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: padding 1s linear;
    transition: padding 1s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jDwCq/11/).

Of course using this approach, you can use transition effects on `color`, `background-color`, `height`, `font-size` `border` (`-width` or `-color`), and adjust the timing (as well as the easing).

To animate multiple properties it's easier to use the keyword `all` (rather than the individual property names).

---

1. Given that I'm over the age of thirty I'm having trouble defining, or even *recognising*, 'cool' these days; but my seven year old nephew assures me that animating the `padding` looks 'okay.' You may, perhaps, have to consult your own child-relatives for the coolness of alternative approaches.

Comment: I said specifically that i did not want to use height or padding to expand the height just because it affects the sibling rows. If you hover over one of the rows, you'll see that the ones below jumps down, which isn't very nice. The idea was to use `:before` for the top part of the row; just give it the same background as the row and expand the height of the `:before` instead of the actual row. Same thing for the bottom part, but with `:after` instead. This way, it looks like the row is expanding in height.

Comment: So explain, clearly, what you want. Because I think I'm missing something, you want the row to look like it's expanding without actually expanding?

Comment: The actual row itself shouldn't be expanding, that would make the siblings jump around like in your example. What i want is to make the row expand, but instead of taking up space, just overflow it's siblings. Get it?

Comment: This is the final result i was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/LvGQD/. I must admit it doesn't look very good, and i'm probably not going to use it (for this purpose at least), but it works. Do you see the difference between your example and mine?